# Get the same/map bindkeys in shell mode, in particular CTRL-r

Tags: key-bindings, shell-mode

I am using emacs s 23.1.1.
I have started to really use in real-earnest the shell, in order to minimize the amounts of time I am out of emacs. However, the bind-keys are emacs based. Which is good, but has its' limitations. if I want to use CTRL-r in the shell-context (loop backward over commands input), and not in the emacs context, how do I do that?
 Having a preceding bind-key is O.K. I.e. press bindy key ALT-CTRL-S, and then CTRL-r.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you are asking. Are you asking how to unbind particular keys in shell mode? If so, then just bind them to `nil` in `shell-mode-map`.

Comment: Try using `term` or `ansi-term`.

Comment: Hello drew. I am trying to get the normal shell bind keys to override the emacs bind-keys, automatically.

Answer (score 3):

By default the binding to do this in Emacs' shell-mode is M-r which runs the command `comint-history-isearch-backward-regexp`.  This allows you to search backwards though your input history using a regular expression.

Personally I prefer the `comint-previous-matching-input-from-input` command, which is by default bound to C-c M-r.  I have it bound to the slightly more convenient M-p and it allows me to type the first few characters of the command I want, and to then use M-p to cycle through all previous inputs that begin with this prefix.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `term-mode` rather than `shell-mode`.  In `term-mode` you can switch between "character mode" (where commands like `C-r` go directly to the terminal) and "line mode" (where commands are first interpreted by Emacs).  `C-c C-j` activates line mode and `C-c C-k` character mode.  Character mode gives `C-r` the behavior you want while line mode makes the terminal act more like a normal Emacs buffer.